# почему в microsoft edge нету задержки при ресайзе, в отличии от google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Я при разработке всё время пользуюсь Chrome и люблю двигать окно инспектора Chrome, чтобы адаптивно верстать. Я писал одну программу и решил залезть в Microsoft Edge и решил там подвигать его инспектор. Я был крайне удивлён тому, что я не чувствовал абсолютно подглючивания интерфейса, которое было в Chrome. Мне очень интересно, с чем это связано, почему рендер при ресайзе окна намного лучше в Edge, чем в Chrome. В чём принципиальная разница, что интерфейс Edge вообще не глючит при двигании ползунка? У меня 8гб оперативной памяти, intel i5-3330, gtx 1060 3gb, windows 10
.

Comment: Мое предположение, эдж работает с интервалом, в то время как хром при малейшем изменении окна его перерисовывает. Это не правильно, нет смысла на каждый микро шаг перерисовывать полностью окно, нужно делать это либо с небольшим интервалом, либо до конечно точки.